# Jquery POST and AJAX prepend double space to returned data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I am still struggling with this problem after about 2 weeks with no sign of a solution.

Any data that is returned by PHP using $.ajax or $.post always has two spaces added onto the returned data. I have trimmed the data being echoed in PHP to confirm it's not an issue with the server or my scripts.

e.g.

```
echo '{"id": "'.$myId.'"}';
```

Becomes:

```
'  {"id": "'.$myId.'"}'
```

When viewing the returned data in inspector. This causes problems for my js scripts because they expect nothing returned when there is no error. Double space is returned which causes errors when there are actually none, which in turn stops other events from firing.

I am using Jquery 1.8.3.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this extremely strange and annoying issue?

---

I am using NetBeans

---

I recall that this only started happening since I moved my app to a new server, but I don't see how that would have effected it in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful,

I think there is a whitespace in your script (may be from included files, but not sure). You can overcome this by clearing the output buffer, before you send the data to browser. The following code will demonstrate the idea.

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo ' '; // Possible whitespace (may be from included files)

----------
----------

if (YOUR_CHECK_FOR_AJAX_REQUEST) {
    ob_end_clean();
    $myId = 1;
    echo '{"id": "'.$myId.'"}';
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is chance that you've got whitespaces at the end of your included php files (to prevent it, skip ending `?>` tag).

Also you should check if there is nothing in front of `<?php` and disable BOM in your UTF-8 files.

Comment: I have no ending ?> but how do I check if BOM is enabled in NetBeans?

Comment: @imperium2335 From what I know, NetBeans is not using BOM in UTF-8 files so it's not a problem here. Temporary fix is trimming returned data.

Answer (score 0):

The data which is returned from the file would have spaces or you would have html tags. Remove all the tags, lines, spaces and at the end remove **?>**

If you are returning data from test.php the file should look like as below

```
<?php
$myId = '1';
echo '{"id": "'.$myId.'"}';
```

Comment: There are no spaces before or after any of my code and I have no closing ?>

Comment: Trim the echo data like $data = '{"id": "'.$myId.'"}'; echo trim($data);

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam But why want you to trim static data? Beginning and ending of that string is defined by you and you know that it doesn't contain any whitespaces.